# Regex - Match several groups

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to extract from the following example string (all in one line):

```
First Note Type[br]03/11/2015          12:51:24            USR123[br]Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country[br]Second Note Type[br]03/11/2015          16:26:03            USR456[br]The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
```

**2 matches** with **5 groups each**, e.g.:

**Match 1**:

- G1 -> 'First Note Type'
- G2 -> '03/11/2015'
- G3 -> '12:51:24'
- G4 -> 'USR123'
- G5 -> 'Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country[br]'

**Match 2**:

- G1 -> 'Second Note Type'
- G2 -> '03/11/2015'
- G3 -> '16:26:03'
- G4 -> 'USR456'
- G5 -> 'The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.'

So far I've only managed to match the first 4 groups using the following expression:

```
([a-zA-Z\s]+)\\[br\\\]([0-9]+/[0-9]+/[0-9]+)\s+([0-9]+:[0-9]+:[0-9]+)\s+([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\\[br\\]
```

could not get also the fifth (G5) group, I've tried adding a `(.+)` but will result in only a single match instead of `n`

can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `(.+)`, it matches 1 or more symbols other than a newline, as many times as possible (so, it will eat up everything up to the end of line).

You can match it with the following regex:

```
([a-zA-Z\s]+)\[br]([0-9]+/[0-9]+/[0-9]+)\s+([0-9]+:[0-9]+:[0-9]+)\s+([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\[br]([^[]*(?:\[(?!br])[^[]*)*(?:\[br])?)
```

See [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%5ba-zA-Z%5cs%5d%2b)%5c%5bbr%5d(%5b0-9%5d%2b%2f%5b0-9%5d%2b%2f%5b0-9%5d%2b)%5cs%2b(%5b0-9%5d%2b%3a%5b0-9%5d%2b%3a%5b0-9%5d%2b)%5cs%2b(%5ba-zA-Z0-9%5d%2b)%5c%5bbr%5d(%5b%5e%5b%5d*(%3f%3a%5c%5b(%3f!br%5d)%5b%5e%5b%5d*)*(%3f%3a%5c%5bbr%5d)%3f)&i=First+Note+Type%5bbr%5d03%2f11%2f2015++++++++++12%3a51%3a24++++++++++++USR123%5bbr%5dNow+is+the+time+for+all+good+men+to+come+to+the+aid+of+their+country%5bbr%5dSecond+Note+Type%5bbr%5d03%2f11%2f2015++++++++++16%3a26%3a03++++++++++++USR456%5bbr%5dThe+quick+brown+fox+jumped+over+the+lazy+dog.)

I added `([^[]*(?:\[(?!br])[^[]*)*(?:\[br])?)` part. It matches everything other than `[br]`. A more detailed breakdown:

- `[^[]*` - match 0 or more characters other than `[`
- `(?:\[(?!br])[^[]*)*` - match 0 or more sequences of...

  - `\[(?!br])` -  a literal `[` not followed with `br]`
  - `[^[]*` - 0 or more characters other than `[`.
- `(?:\[br])?` - matches 1 or 0 times a literal sequence `[br]`

Results obtained with your string as input:

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer, I've tried it and It almost worked! problem is i need to include also the "[br]" in "G5" group (see my example M1-G5 ends with a "[br]"), I've given a poor example basically any G5 group can contains several "[br]", is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: just add it as an optional group: `(?:\[br])?`. I updated the answer. Note that you do not need to escape `]` outside of a character class.

Comment: thank you it worked! I was not aware of such feature, have a nice day!